# Returning results/erros from WCF services. Complex type or an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, custom-exceptions

A few days ago I asked a very similar question. I was about returning values/errors inside the application. I accept an answer to not return error as and object but throw an custom exceptions.
Now, I'm not exactly sure how to deal with it using WCF services. I wish the service will be as simple as it could be for client.

Speaking very generally, my project looks like that: 
Client -> WCF Service application -> Database.

Inside WCF app I've got my own exception class, and it works fine. But let's say client want sth from db. My question is: 
What should I return to the client outside my app?
A. Complex type: A value with meta data (information about a possible error[1]). And when really unexpected error occurs throw an exception.
B. Just a value (when possible error occurs - throw an exception)

[1] - invalid string format, can't connect to database or sth like that. I mean - If I know what the error exactly is - why throw an exception to client - I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Try `Either` (also called `Tagged Union`) [construction](https://siliconcoding.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/either_in_csharp/), which holds either a Value, or an Error. It turned out very powerful when I used it in WCF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decision how to tackle this problem depends on the client. If you have to support Silverlight Clients, throwing exceptions is out of the picture because Silverlight Clients using the browser HTTP Stack cannot deal with them. For Silverlight Clients I generally recommend (and use myself) the approach described [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/01/27/returning-exception-information-to-a-silverlight-client-through-wcf.aspx).

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure about the client - it could be silverlight. So using Fault contract, like Tim said, is not a good idea in that case, right?

Comment: I very like that solution. I'm gonna use my WCF service in ASP.NET web application. But is it very bad to use it with WPF or Windows Form client?

Comment: I will follow example described in your link. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By design, WCF hides exceptions from the client.  It's up to the developer to determine what, if any, information is returned to the client when an exception occurs.

I would look at using `FaultContract` or `FaultContract<T>`, and return exceptions that you wish to via that mechanism.

Here's some articles to look at:

[Fault Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx)
[WCF Tutorial Fault Contract](http://wcftutorial.net/Fault-Contract.aspx)

You might also want to look at IErrorHandler for WCF:

[IErrorHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx)

Comment: Fault Contract - this is what I'm using now. When an error/exception occurs I throw my "fault contract" exception to client. I'm not sure about that. In your first link (with calculator example) - service could detect if the number is zero and return that information to client by a simple message - not an exception.

Comment: I would expect a robust service (or application) to handle expected exceptions in a non-exception manner (I hope that makes sense).  I was suggesting FaultContracts as a way of returning exception data to the client for an unexpected issue.  And, as Oliver Wiechhold pointed out, it's completely useless for Silverlight (which, not having worked with Silverlight I didn't know).  For returning results (even error-type results like divide by zero) I would have the service return it as the message, not an exception, as you said.